# Github API returns 404, but default http request returns 301

Tags: redirect, github-api

I try to get Github repository info.

1. At first some test. I have next url:

   > https://github.com/airbnb/rendr

   When I paste it to my browser, it redirects me to

   > https://github.com/rendrjs/rendr

   If I try first link via curl, it returns status 301 with `Location: https://github.com/rendrjs/rendr`
2. I try to get repository info using Github API. For this we should call something like this:

   `https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo`

   But when I try `curl -i "https://api.github.com/repos/airbnb/rendr"` I get 404 error; for `curl -i "https://api.github.com/repos/rendrjs/rendr"` I get the info and status 200. If I add `Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json` header (for using `API v3`, default is `beta`) I have the same result.

So, can I somehow get repository info using Github API and the first link? I expected at least 301 like a default http request.

Comment: Yeah, currently the GitHub API doesn't redirect repository resources after renames happen. You might consider using repository IDs to fetch repositories, instead of their names. For example, try fetching https://api.github.com/repositories/6479425 instead. Fetching this resource should work even if the repository is renamed.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your response, I'll try another solutions.

Comment: @IvanZuzak any way to systematically get id of a repo given the old name?

Comment: @RayShan for public repositories, you could fetch the github.com resource (not the api.github.com resource), and see where you're redirected and then use that new name.

Comment: @IvanZuzak thanks I was hoping not to have to do this but there doesn't appear to be another choice

Comment: The GitHub API will soon provide redirects by default for renamed/relocated repositories. In the meantime, you can gain access to the redirects by specifying a custom preview media type in the `Accept` header: `application/vnd.github.quicksilver-preview+json`. You can read the announcement regarding this change at https://developer.github.com/changes/2015-04-17-preview-repository-redirects/, and you can see example usage at https://gist.github.com/jasonrudolph/56388a4ff51b4f721cac.